# Python: pos tag - with word 'back'

Tags: python, spacy, pos-tagger

How to distinguish the post tag of back in the following sentences:

1. experiencing intermittent shooting pain in her lower back following the collision
2. somewhere in the back of my head

Examples from spacy

```
doc = nlp(u'experiencing intermittent shooting pain in her lower back following the collision')

for token in doc:
    print(token.text, token.pos_, token.tag_, token.dep_)

#experiencing VERB VBG ROOT
#intermittent ADJ JJ amod
#shooting NOUN NN compound
#pain NOUN NN dobj
#in ADP IN prep
#her ADJ PRP$ poss
#lower ADJ JJR advmod
#back ADV RB pobj
#following VERB VBG prep
#the DET DT det
#collision NOUN NN pobj

doc = nlp(u'somewhere in the back of my head')

for token in doc:
    print(token.text, token.pos_, token.tag_, token.dep_)

#somewhere ADV RB ROOT
#in ADP IN prep
#the DET DT det
#back NOUN NN pobj
#of ADP IN prep
#my ADJ PRP$ poss
#head NOUN NN pobj
```

Intuitively, 'back' in 1 is NOUN and 2 is ADV?? When extracting NOUN from the above sentences, I was expecting 'back' in 'her lower back' to be extracted out. So, how to make it happen?

Also, got confused with pos tagging results, how to know if pos tagging is working properly?

Answer (score 0):

the pos-tagging results can be confusing.

One thing that might help you taking noun chunks. Or make rules for getting custom chunks: usually tri-grams and bi-grams of pos-tags identified form your data and then use the pos tags of these chunks to tag the words in the chunk.